# Unable to set up Twilio SDK on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to integrate TWILIO in my app using

```
implementation group: "com.twilio.sdk", name: "twilio", version: "8.7.0"
```

but am getting the following error

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'.
```

Then after searching this error I found that it can be resolved by adding

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
}
```

After adding the app now built successfully. After running the app I got the following error

```
Caused by: j.a.a.b.b: java.lang.ClassCastException: The application has specified that a custom LogFactory implementation should be used but Class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl' cannot be converted to 'org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory'. Please check the custom implementation
```

then to solve this error I added

```
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
```

to the proguard-rules file

After running the code again I get the following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; 

in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; 

or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes3.dex)
```

To which I'm not able to find a solution. Could someone please help me resolve these error to add TWILIO to my project?

---

Edit - 1

After adding print in the code I found out the line of code cause the above error is

```
Token token = Token.creator().create();
```

I'm trying to implement the following code

```
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Token;

public class Example {
 // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/console
 // and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
 public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = System.getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
 public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = System.getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
    Token token = Token.creator().create();

    System.out.println(token.getUsername());
 }
}
```

from

```
https://www.twilio.com/docs/stun-turn
```

Answer (score 1):

**Voice Android 3.2.0+**

```
# Twilio Programmable Voice
-keep class com.twilio.** { *; }
-keep class tvo.webrtc.** { *; }
-dontwarn tvo.webrtc.**
-keep class com.twilio.voice.** { *; }
-keepattributes InnerClasses
```

These rules ensure that the Programmable Voice library is not removed by ProGuard.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/voip-sdk/android

Comment: I added these to my proguard-rules but got the following error: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes3.dex)

Comment: Do you know how can I resolve the above error?